# How to get brightest color in Mat with Java OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV in Java. I have a mat, let's say, `input`, that is formatted in BGR, with blue on channel 0, green on channel 1, and red on channel 2. I am trying to generate a new mat that, for each pixel, has the brightest channel at that pixel at full intensity. For example, if the input mat has a point with BGR values `(15, 84, 198)`, then the output mat, at that same point, should have `(0, 0, 255)`. I could loop over each point manually, but this processing happens every frame, and I fear that this would be too slow. I am confident that there is a quick and easy way to do this with some native functions, but I cannot find any. Is there any way to do this processing quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Any function that does this will still have to loop through the mat, so there really isn't much to be saved other than regular loop optimization? Have you done any testing to see if this actually has a noticeable impact on the frame rate? We will need a lot more information about the process if you want more help. On performance, how accurate does it have to be? You could increase the performance by only checking 1 pixel out of every 4 (effectively rendering at a lower resolution) and upscaling it, or check one pixel, and draw 4, but it all depends if the bottleneck is the loop, or the drawing

Comment: sounds like you want to use `cv.cvtColor(im, cv.BGR2HSV)`, dial the **saturation** up on everything, convert back. -- please review [ask] and [mre]. at least show your own effort, including input data. show your research (googlings).